# when plotting with vbar on an xaxis that's a datetime axis, how can I set the width of the bars to be "one day"?

Tags: python, bokeh

This certainly makes the width of the bars wider, but would be better to set them to "1 day" wide:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", height=200, ...)
...
c.vbar('dt', top='pct_change', width=100000000, source=source)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give a `timedelta` object as the width keyword argument, it will be converted to milliseconds.

```
import datetime

...

c.vbar('dt', top='pct_change', width=datetime.timedelta(days=1), source=source)
```

[`NumberSpec`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html#bokeh.core.properties.NumberSpec) can accept `datetime` values, unless `accept_datetime` is set to `false`.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting? I would be interseted to know.

Comment: Me too, this had not occurred to me, but seems perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying units of a datetime axis are milliseconds-since-epoch, so to make a bar be "1 day" wide, set the width to be the number of milliseconds a day, i.e. 24*60*60*1000 = 86400000